# How do I execute the stats file in SPSS 21?

Tags: ibm

I have just installed the Linux version of IBM statistical package SPSS 21 and according to instructions in order to run SPSS I just need to run stats file in the `/bin` directory. Everything is ordered, that is stats file is in `/bin` catalogue and everything is fine, but I don't know how to run it from the terminal.

Comment: I suggest that instead of SPSS, you do `sudo apt-get install pspp` and try using that. PSPP is faster than SPSS and ironically many people have reported that it is more reliable too.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy/paste the text in the **stats** file to the terminal, by drag and drop. This works for me on 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SPSS for Linux does not come with a menu entry or file associations.

To start SPSS, you have to open a terminal and execute

```
/opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/21/bin/statistics
```

for version 21. For other versions, replace the "21" by the correct version number.

I wasn't able to open a file by appending the file name to the command.

---

Alternatively, you can create a menu entry yourself. Create a file `SPSS.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications/` and put into it

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=SPSS
Exec=/opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/21/bin/statistics
```

You can add [other fields](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html); for example I added `Icon=view-statistics`, which gives me a histogram-like icon, but whether that works for you depends on your installed icon sets; this one seems to come with KDE.